# How to customize size of UAModalPanel?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uamodalpanel

Usually I would initialize a UAModalPanel like below, and it would work fine

```
modalPanel = [[[UAExampleModalPanel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds withView:@"modalPanel_iPhone"] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:modalPanel];
modalPanel.delegate = self;
[modalPanel showFromPoint:modalPanel.view.center];
```

but if I try changing the first line to below, I cannot click the X button to close the subview. What am I doing wrong?

```
modalPanel = [[[UAExampleModalPanel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,100) withView:@"modalPanel_iPhone"] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the author of [UAModalPanel](https://github.com/coneybeare/UAModalPanel). You **always** initialize the panel with the full sized frame of the window, so the dark mask can reach full screen. Then, if you want to adjust the panel size, you tweak the margin and padding of the panel, as shown on [Step 4 in the ReadMe](https://github.com/coneybeare/UAModalPanel#step-4-customize-uamodalpanel) on the Github page.